# Detect which address client entered to land on a website

Tags: url, redirect, dns

Since it is possible to link different domain names to the same webserver, is it possible to detect which address [can be the ip address] a client entered to access a website, so it is possible to implement conditions depending on this value?

I'm maybe totally wrong about the multiple domain names. I don't know a lot about dns and domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see it in the HTTP `Host:` header. For example, if you're running a PHP script, you can see it in `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

Comment: So let's say "rakamai.com" and "marakai.com" both points to 13.14.15.16, HTTP_HOST will contextualy contains either one or the other depending on what the user typed in his browser?